# Handling terminal colour codes ( ANSI colour escape codes ) in python

Tags: python, openwrt

[image]

I was supposed to write a PyQt application which can communicate with serial devices over UART. I connected it to an OpenWRT based router and when I tried to run 'ls' on it, the output ( see attached screenshot ) had some weird letters around the name of the folders. I understand that these are Color codes of some sort. How do I remove these from the output or display the colour accordingly. 
Any help would help.

Answer (score 2):

See the man page for **ls**(1), and the output of the command

```
$  command -v ls
```

On my Linux system, that reports

```
$ command -v ls
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

It's a fact of life that a Unix interactive shell cannot reliably determine the characteristics of the attached terminal, and a regrettable fact that GNU colorization is indifferent to the terminal.  When connecting with a device that doesn't want color, the best plan is just to turn it off wherever it crops up.

To test that, one quick trick is to type "ls" this way:

```
$ \ls
```

The introductory backslash defeats the shell's alias mechanism, and reverts to using bare `/usr/bin/ls`, or whatever your `PATH` supplies.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply james , I understand your answer but my problem is that this tool would be used with many devices, many of which i would not have prior access to. There are tools like 'screen' which are able to somehow parse that information and display the color accordingly, I need something which can either do that or remove the codes all together.

Comment: You don't need access to the device.  Upon connection, simply establish your environment per your needs.  Use your shell-fu: **unalias** and **unset** every command you support/use.  I really think that's your only option.  I doubt a program exists that will filter out ANSI control sequences.  The task is complicated and ill-specified: the program would have to filter any control sequence for any device defined in termcap (or whatever).  Anything that did claim to do that would be apt to introduce as many problems as it solves.